# Deriving a relation between entropy, volume and particles through the chemical potential

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I'm a teaching assistant on a first year course on Introduction to Thermodynamics based on the book "Molecular Driving Forces" by Dill & Bromberg.

There's a question which asks the students to derive the following relation between S, V and N:

$S(V,N) = Nkln(V)$

A simple solution that is hinted is to use the differential form of the fundamental entropy equation and realizing the following identities (assuming an ideal gas):

$\frac{P}{T} = (\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{U,N}=\frac{Nk}{V}$

$ds = Nk\int \frac{dV}{V} \rightarrow \Delta S = Nkln(\frac{V_2}{V_1})$

Now, I've meditated about and have been asked by several students the following question: could we arrive to the same (or equivalent) expression through a chemical potential route? After all, we need an expression that relates S *both* to N and V. Unfortunately, I have not been able to give a satisfactory answer.

Here's what I've tried, arriving to some ugly looking equation that intuitively looks incorrect to me:

Use the definition:
$\frac{\mu_j}{T}=-(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N_j})_{U,V,N_{j\neq i}}$, which also stems from the fundamental differential entropy equation.

Now I make the assumption that the chemical potential is equal to the density of molecules in the ideal gas. This is what I'm most dubious about, although I couldn't think of another way in which to have a relation to it. If that holds, I can then write the following identities:

$\mu = \frac{n}{V}$ then $P=\mu kT$

$\frac{-P}{T^2k} = \frac{\mu}{T} = (\frac{\partial S}{\partial N_j})_{U,V,N_{j\neq i}}$

Now because $P = \frac{nkT}{V}$,

$\frac{-P}{T^2k} = \frac{-nkT}{VT^2k}=\frac{-n}{VT}=(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N_j})_{U,V,N_{j\neq i}}$

Which I think can be solved:

$\int dS = \int \frac{-n}{VT}dn \rightarrow \Delta S = -\frac{\Delta n^2}{2VT}$

This result doesn't really make much sense to me (a negative entropy (?)). I'm a bit confused, because the first 'route' seems so simple but this second attempt looks fairly involved.

So, what I wrong in my logic? Apologies beforehand if I'm doing something egregiously wrong, it's been awhile since I've had to solve these 'pen and paper' problems.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help, but I'm sure that $\int n \, dn \neq \Delta n$.

Comment: Also, I think that using this relationship between chemical potential and entropy won't lead to your result, since this relationship holds $V$ constant, and you want to get to entropy as a function of a variable $V$ and $n$. But, that I might have wrong.

Comment: @ralk912 d'oh! Thanks for the heads up on the integral, will update the correct result now.
Also, as far as I'm aware, isn't that what's happening on the first correct solution to the problem? Where $N$ is being treated as a constant, although $S$ depends on both $V$ and $n$.

Comment: Well, $N$ is treated constant because it's for that particular case (i.e. this is valid for gas expansions/compressions). If both $N$ and $V$ were to vary, then the first derivation wouldn't be valid. You're trying to get to an expression where $N$ is constant and $V$ varies from one where $V$ is constant and $N$ varies.

Comment: Also, from a dimensional analysis, you're assumption says that $\mu$ has $\pu{mol dm-3}$ units, while the definition implies the correct $\pu{J mol-1}$ units for chemical potential. So I think that assumption is not valid.

Comment: I see your point, after all the chemical potential *is* a kind of energy (the Gibbs free energy at constant $T$ and $P$), and not the density. I just used that assumption because I could not think of another way to have the chemical potential appear in the general gas equation. Also, the final expression I've arrived to implies that the entropy *becomes more negative* as the number of particles increases for a fixed $V$ and $T$, which does not resonate well with my chemical intuition. After all, shouldn't more particles in a system have more dofs to explore and *increase* the entropy?